# How can I configure Amazon Cloudfront to serve my Gatsby application correctly?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, gatsby

I'm trying to serve my GatsbyJS application using `Amazon S3` and `Amazon Cloudfront`.
Gatsby generates static and dynamic routes:

foo -> public and static route.
bar -> private and dynamic route.

Pages that doesn't require authentication, are gonna have a static index.html.
/foo is gonna generate an /foo/index.html file.

Pages that does require authentication, are gonna exist only inside Gatsby, so Cloudfront should serve the root index.html
/bar is gonna render the root index.html so that React will hydrate it and show the correct Component.

How can I make Couldfront understand that, if I call `/foo` and there's a `index.html` inside the `foo` folder, it should be rendered, if not, render the index.html?

Comment: If the origin of cloudfront is static website endpoint , it will load index.html if you have specified it as index document. /foo -->/foo/index.html

Comment: @JamesDean so I should enable S3's `Static Web Hosting` and use CF as before?